# Problems transforming XML

Tags: xml, xslt, marc

I am trying to transform a MARCXML file to MODS XML format, but have been having lots of problems.

Here is an example valid MARCXML file
http://ebba.english.ucsb.edu/content/marcxml.html

I'm using a XSLT file from the organisation that created the format in the first place:
http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/mods-conversions.html

In particular this XSLT
http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/MARC21slim2MODS3-6.xsl

When I put the two together the transformation fails.

I've tried several online transformation tools.  One returns this error message:

```
Internal Server Error: <html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Internal Server Error</body></html>
```

And on another site it actually does work as expected:
http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

Why then can't I get the transformation to work in .Net or any of the other online tools?
Is there something wrong with the syntax of the XML or XSLT?

Comment: My tool at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJe uses your input and the XSLT 2.0 stylesheet http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/MARC21slim_MODS3-6_XSLT2-0.xsl without problems. It uses the .NET version of Saxon 9.8 HE.

Comment: And https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJe/1 uses the XSLT 1 stylesheet you have linked to together with Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform and also runs without problems.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks! Thats an impressive site, very useful.  I discovered the cause of my .Net problem (see answer below).  But doesn't explain why plenty of other online sites have trouble with it

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have another problem with a second type of XML document, can you help? - https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJe/2

Comment: Consider to ask a new question for the separate problem, detailing in the StackOverflow question what input you have, which stylesheet you use and which result you expect. You can additionally link to the xsltfiddle sample to demonstrate the problem, but we need a clear textual description of what you want to achieve and which result you expect.

Comment: @MartinHonnen ok Martin, new question submitted here if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756874/xslt-transformation-returns-empty-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer to a previous question solved my problem:

> XslCompiledTransform.Transform" takes XmlReader as first Parameter and
>   i was passing XmlDocument in First Paramenter

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548147/white-space-cannot-be-stripped-from-input-documents-that-have-already-been-loade](http://This%20answer%20to%20a%20previous%20question%20solved%20my%20problem%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548147/white-space-cannot-be-stripped-from-input-documents-that-have-already-been-loade)