# XSLT transformation returns empty XML

Tags: xml, xslt, dublin-core, marc

I am trying to transform a [Dublin Core XML](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dublin_Core) file to [MODS XML](http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/) format, but the transformation results in empty XML.

The XSLT I'm using is from here:
http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/mods-conversions.html

Here is an example DC XML file and the XSLT:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJe/2

I'm not getting any errors, and in theory this should work, but the resultant XML is empty.

Comment: If the xml nodes do not match the xslt structure, the structure will be empty with no errors ... Try parsing the xml node by node

Comment: The stylesheet seems to expect to process elements in certain namespaces, like the Dublin Core namespace `xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"`. Your sample XML does not use that namespace at all, nor any of the other namespaces that stylesheet seems to expect to process.