# XslCompiledTransform result won't display in browser properly

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am attempting to convert an XML file into an HTML file (and then, ultimately, into a pdf) by way of XslCompiledTransform, however the end result will not display in a browser and it seems to be because it is adding an extra <?xml tag at the beginning of the file following by a random  tag which contains the real <?xml tag and actual html structure/data.  Manually removing those two extra items results in the proper display of the file in a browser, but I am not sure why this is even happening (new to XML transforms and Xsl in general).  Here is the c# code:

```
private void GenerateHtmlBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Getting file path    
            string strXSLTFile = "Z:\\Database\\Report.xslt";
            string strXMLFile = "Z:\\Database\\Export.xml";

            // Creating XSLCompiled object    
            XslCompiledTransform objXSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile);

            // Creating StringBuilder object to hold html data and creates TextWriter object to hold data from XslCompiled.Transform method    
            StringBuilder htmlOutput = new StringBuilder();
            TextWriter htmlWriter = new StringWriter(htmlOutput);

            // Creating XmlReader object to read XML content    
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strXMLFile);

            // Call Transform() method to create html string and write in TextWriter object.    
            objXSLTransform.Transform(reader, null, htmlWriter);
            textBox2.Text = htmlWriter.ToString();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Z:\\Database\\Export.html", FileMode.Create))
            {

                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));

                ser.Serialize(fs, htmlOutput.ToString());
            }

            // Closing xmlreader object    
            reader.Close();
            
        }
```

and this is the XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    
  <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfPerson">
      <xsl:for-each select="Person">
        <div style="background-color:gray;color:white;padding:4px">
          <span style="font-weight:bold">
            Name: <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
          </span>
          - Id: <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
          <span style="font-style:italic">
            Current Value: <xsl:value-of select="CurrentValue"/>
          </span>
          <span style="font-style:italic">
             Simulated Value: <xsl:value-of select="SimulatedValue"/>
          </span>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
```

And lastly here is the end result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE"><div style="background-color:gray;color:white;padding:4px"><span style="font-weight:bold">
            Name: Full Test3</span>
          - Id: 3344558</div><div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt"><span style="font-style:italic">
            Current EFC: 1500</span><span style="font-style:italic">
             Simulated EFC: 7</span></div></body></html></string>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You get the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and the `<string>` because you use `XmlSerializer` on the result string of the XSLT transformation. I have no idea why you think you need to do that, if you want the result of the XSLT transformation in a file then the easiest is using the overload of the `Transform` method taking two file names e.g. `objXSLTransform.Transform(strXMLFile, "Z:\\Database\\Export.html")`.

Comment: My god....yup.  I didn't realize the transform could output, and so I added that.  Stupid now that I think it through.  It works now, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the comments mentions, DO NOT use XmlSerializer to output a file.  I removed that part and tried to specify an output file, but the output (while solving the extra tag symptom) did not have any HTML or XML output within it (only the values fed in from the XML). Ultimately I used the answer from: [White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548147/white-space-cannot-be-stripped-from-input-documents-that-have-already-been-loade)

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score -1):

The XSLT file is completely skewed.

To eliminate XML prolog declaration from the output, the following clause shall be in the XSLT:

```
omit-xml-declaration="yes"
```

Additional notes:

- It is not clear what is the desired output: complete HTML or a
  fragment of it. It is possible to specify `method="html"` if needed.
- c# for XSLT transformation could be improved.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So when I replace the top of my XSLT file with what you've written, it does get rid of the extra <?xml tag in the result, but it a.) still makes a random string tag that everything is contained within, and b.) now doesn't generate any HTML tags at all (visual studio also gives me a message saying I can't have foreach items within xsl:stylesheet elements?).  I think I may end up creating an HTML file as a template and feeding in the data as the tags will always be the same.  But I would like to know/understand why I can't get this method to work (for future projects).

Comment: Please connect with me on LinkedIn